# Apache Ignite unique constraint

Tags: spring-data, ignite, unique-constraint

I'm using Apache Ignite with Spring Data. I need a column "username" to be unique. In fact "username" is the key of the Ignite cache. I think ignite doesn't implement unique constraint yet. 
Using plain ignite API, I'm not sure if I can do a lock like:

```
IgniteCache<String, Integer> cache = ignite.cache("userCache");
Lock lock = cache.lock("username1");
lock.lock();
//check if doesn't exist yet
...
```

as "username1" doesn't exist yet. Is there other approach?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your approach will work, however, there is a suitable method for what you are trying to achieve: [IgniteCache.putIfAbsent](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-)

Comment: I guess with your suggestion I cannot use Spring Data. It has to be vanilla ignite. Currently I'm using a pessimisticTransactionManager and it works. But I guess even with optimistic (serializable isolation) should work as well. In fact I think it will behave more or less like the SQL constraint, as only duplicated names will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Current solution with Spring Data and [SpringTransactionManager](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/transactions/spring/SpringTransactionManager.html) is:

```
@Transactional("pessimisticTransactionManager")
public void create(final User user) throws AlreadyExistsException {
    logger.info("Creating {}", user);
    if(userRepository.findByName(user.getName()).isPresent()) {
        throw new AlreadyExistsException(user.getName() + " already in use.") ;
    }
    userRepository.save(user.getName(), user);      
}
```

but with optimisticTransactionManager should also work and have better performance as the chance of collision in names is low for my system.