# How can we add Unique constraint to Apache ignite table column while creating table?

Tags: mysql, ignite

I'm new to the `Apache Ignite`, I want to create a table with **Primary-Key** as well as **Unique-key** constraint to my table.
I'm not able to add `Unique-key` constraint to the table as it is not supported by Ignite.

Do we have any other way for adding composite unique constraint to more than one column in Ignite?

Here is example for SQL Syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
`id` int,
`first_name` varchar(255),
`last_name` varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`first_name`,`last_name`)
)
```

This is just a sample table.

Comment: The code is correct (after removing a typo - adding lost backtick). For MySQL at least.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for Ignite SQL Conformance:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/sql-conformance
see: E141 Basic integrity constraints

This answer might help your use case: [Apache Ignite unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701750/apache-ignite-unique-constraint)